# axios post request to send form data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, multipartform-data, use-effect

I am using Axios post request to fill all the data but in backend its giving undefined value for each fields in form I want to know how to post all the data in `formData` in Axios because its giving in empty data in Axios post request.

I am using `FormData` to append all the fields in Axios data body I am attaching the screenshot post requirement fields which needed in form.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


export default function Form(props) {
 
  var bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append("sale", "");
  bodyFormData.append("district", "");
  bodyFormData.append("billing", "");
  
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/form",
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      //handle success
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      //handle error
      console.log(response);
    });
  const { search } = useLocation();

  const urlParams = Object.fromEntries([...new URLSearchParams(search)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(urlParams);
  }, [urlParams]);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState("EUR");
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("get", JSON.stringify(data));
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid
        container
        container
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
          <Card
            className="p-4 mb-4"
            style={{
              height: 765,
              transform: "rotateX(15deg)",
            }}
          >
                <div
                  className="heading"
                  style={{
                    marginTop: -73,
                    fontSize: 38,
                    marginRight: 15,
                    color: "#002699",
                  }}
                >
                  <h5>Action Tracker</h5>
                </div>
                <form
                  className={classes.form}
                  noValidate
                  onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}
                >
                  <Grid container spacing={4}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        type="text"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                        id="sales"
                        label="Sales office"
                        name="sale"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setSale(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.salesoff}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        type="text"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                        id="billing"
                        label="Billing document"
                        name="billing"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setBilling(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.billingdoc}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    
                    
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                    // onClick={addForm}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                  <Grid container justify="flex-end">
                    <Grid item></Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </form>
              </div>
            </Container>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do `console.log(bodyFormData)` before you make the post request and see what's being posted?

To me that seems like where the error would be if you're getting a success response from axios.

Comment: I am getting empty array after console.log(bodyFormData).

Comment: That's your issue then. Try hardcoding a post request and see if it works. If it does, then you just need to figure out what's wrong with bodyFormData :)

Comment: even I am sending thsi way its getting only getting id sucesss axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/form", {
      sale: "",
      district: "",
    })
    .then(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

Comment: I have tried hardcoding same answer I am getting only getting id @theabrar

Answer (score 0):

Why not do these operations in the function you submitted the form?

Have you tried doing it this way?

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
   var bodyFormData = new FormData();
   bodyFormData.append("sale", "");
   bodyFormData.append("district", "");
   bodyFormData.append("billing", "");
      
     await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/form",
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          //handle success
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          //handle error
          console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

In fact, if you want, update the form data when submitting the form directly, not with change.

Comment: I have tried this way also nothing getting in console

Comment: `const onSubmit = async (sale, district, biling) => {
 bodyFormData.append("sale", sale);
   bodyFormData.append("district", district);
   bodyFormData.append("billing", billing); }`

have you tried?

Comment: yes I have tried nothing getting in console @gucal

Comment: `let config:{
 headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
}
 axios .post("localhost:8080/form", { sale: "", district: "", }, config) .then( (response) => { console.log(response); }, (error) => { console.log(error); } );`

This is my last suggestion :) Good luck